# Query for retrieving data from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am a newbie in SQL and I have a doubt about a query.

I have three tables:

1. Consumer which has fields cons_id_no, key_id
2. bm_bill which has fields key_id, bill_id_no, amt_payable, bill_date
   (It will contain all of bill amounts and date of a consumer)
3. mreceipt which has fields key_id, receipt_no, amt_paid, fine, pay_date (It
   will contain all of the payment details of a consumer)

The consumer table has one to many relationship with bm_bill and mreceipt. 
I want to create ledger information of a consumer based on his cons_id_no. It should
contain his cons_id_no, key_id, bill_id_no (latest), bill_date (latest), amt_payable (latest),receipt_no (latest), amt_paid (latest), fine (latest), pay_date (latest)
and for that I have created the below query

```
SELECT 
   c.key_id,
   c.cons_id_no consumerid, 
   b.bill_id_no billno,
   TO_CHAR(b.bill_date,'dd-Mon-YYYY') billdate,
   b.amt_payable,
   m.receipt_no receiptno, 
   TO_CHAR(m.pay_date,'dd-Mon-YYYY') paydate,
   m.amt_paid+m.fine amountpaid 
FROM 
   consumer c 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT key_id, MAX(bill_date) AS maxDate FROM bm_bill GROUP BY key_id) maxBillDate 
   ON (maxBillDate.key_id = c.key_id)

   LEFT OUTER JOIN bm_bill b 
   ON (b.key_id = c.key_id AND b.bill_date = maxBillDate.maxDate) 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT key_id, MAX(pay_date) AS maxPayDate FROM mreceipt GROUP BY key_id) maxMReceipt 
   ON (maxMReceipt.key_id = c.key_id)

   LEFT OUTER JOIN mreceipt m 
   ON (m.key_id = c.key_id AND m.pay_date = maxMReceipt.maxPayDate)

WHERE 
   c.cons_id_no='?';
```

I executed the query and it gave me the desired result. Then I noted that the query is too slow and found out that in my solution I have:

```
SELECT key_id, max(bill_date) AS maxDate FROM bm_bill GROUP BY key_id
```

which is retrieving all of the key_ids and bill_dates from the bm_bill where I needed only information of a specific key_id. Above all I have one more query like this in my solution.

Hence my question is: Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining each of 2 tables (bm_bill and mreceipt) twice. First thing I'd try is changing your query to avoid double joins and see if it makes difference, something like :

```
SELECT 
   c.key_id,
   c.cons_id_no consumerid, 
   b.bill_id_no billno,
   TO_CHAR(b.bill_date,'dd-Mon-YYYY') billdate,
   b.amt_payable,
   m.receipt_no receiptno, 
   TO_CHAR(m.pay_date,'dd-Mon-YYYY') paydate,
   m.amt_paid+m.fine amountpaid 
FROM 
   consumer c 

   LEFT JOIN (SELECT key_id,
   bill_id_no, bill_date,amt_payable,receipt_no receiptno , 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key_id ORDER BY bill_date DESC) as rn
   FROM bm_bill)b ON (b.key_id = c.key_id and b.rn =1)


   LEFT JOIN (SELECT key_id,
   pay_date , amt_paid, amt_paid, fine, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY key_id ORDER BY pay_date DESC) as rn
   FROM mreceipt) m ON (m.key_id = c.key_id and m.rn =1)


WHERE 
   c.cons_id_no='?';
```

If that doesn't work well, you may work it around with Oracle "alternative" to SQLServer `OUTER APPLY` - you create 2 functions that return `MAX(bill_date)` and `MAX(pay_date)` respectively , and join them.

Comment: Aren't you retrieving all data from bm_bill and mreceipt?

Comment: @ kaushik: I do, but just once from each (not twice as in the original query).

Comment: Today I learned left outer join and partition by. Using those things I also reached the same query given by you. Can we use the 'c.key_id' inside the derived tables? Then I can reduce the number of rows getting retrieved to a minimum.

Comment: @kaushik: I believe you can't do it directly (as far as I remember, Oracle doesn't have direct support for SQLServer `OUTER APPLY`), but you can make each result of `left join` s functions that returns object type

Comment: I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741879/retrieving-values-from-3-tables) relating to it, using the tip from you.

Answer (score 0):

1- Instead of using `MAX` I would advise you to `ORDER` your data using `DESC`, and to `GROUP` using the `TOP` function instead of `MAX`; also instead of a `LEFT JOIN` I would use a `WHERE X IN (...)`.

2- I don't know how big your data is but if you're in a 10's of millions of lines, then storing your grouped results in a temporarly and indexed table could possibly improve your processing time.

3- Also how often you need to run this query (level of freshness) is relevant: if you don't need the latest results of the past few minutes (but rather the results of the day), then definitely use a temporary storage, you can use it for all your queries of the day.

Comment: @@hadinbe-there is no TOP function in Oracle - check question tags. Ordering is usually slowing down the performance...

Comment: @Art: thank you for the feedback! I didn't know that Oracle didn't have this function.

Answer (score 0):

You said that the query as-is gives you the desired result.  If that is so, then consider the following:

You're joining to a derived table (maxBillDate), and for what purpose?  You're not using the join as a filter, or any of the fields in the table.  So...get rid of it, re-execute your query, and you should see that you get the same results without it.

...same store wity your derived table: maxReceipt

Start there, getting rid of the unnecessary baggage, and see what you think.

Comment: I may be incorrect, but I have a one to many relationship between consumer and bm_bill table and same with mreceipt table. I need data based on the max(bill_date) and max(pay_date), thats why I added it.

Comment: @kaushik -- OK, but my point is, you're not using it.  So if you need it, then you need to add fields from it to your SELECT clause.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! This was a toughie because it cried out for an analytical function like `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` but the two outer joins complicated things. `DENSE_RANK` did the trick though. Here's what I came up with:

```
select * from (
  select
    c.key_id,
    c.cons_id_no consumerid,
    to_char(m.pay_date, 'dd-Mon-YYYY') paydate,
    m.receipt_no receiptno,
    m.amt_paid+m.fine amountpaid,
    dense_rank() over
      (order by m.pay_date desc nulls last) as paydaterank,
    to_char(b.bill_date, 'dd-Mon-YYYY') billdate,
    b.bill_id_no billno,
    b.amt_payable,
    dense_rank() over
      (order by b.bill_date desc nulls last) as billdaterank
 from customer c
 left outer join mreceipt m on c.key_id = m.key_id
 left outer join bm_bill b on c.key_id = b.key_id
 where c.cons_id_no = '?'
)
where paydaterank = 1 and billdaterank = 1
```

I tested this under the following conditions:

1. bm_bill had multiple related rows and mreceipt had no related rows
2. mreceipt had multiple related rows and bm_bill had no rows
3. bm_bill and mreceipt had related rows

In each case it worked, but with a radical rewrite like this you'll want to test more.

Also note that I focused on the dates and ID's to figure this out, then added all your other columns later. Check the list of columns for typos or omissions - I did a quick check after I typed everything out but I may have missed something.