# Retrieving values from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have three tables:

1. Consumer which has fields cons_id_no, key_id
2. bm_bill which has fields key_id, bill_id_no, amt_payable, bill_date
   (It will contain all of bill amounts and date of a consumer)
3. mreceipt which has fields key_id, receipt_no, amt_paid, fine,
   pay_date (It will contain all of the payment details of a consumer)

The consumer table has one to many relationship with bm_bill and mreceipt. I want to create ledger information of a consumer based on his cons_id_no. It should contain his cons_id_no, key_id, bill_id_no (latest), bill_date (latest), amt_payable (latest),receipt_no (latest), amt_paid (latest), fine (latest), pay_date (latest) and for that I have created the below query

I have asked the question ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15575157/query-for-retrieving-data-from-3-tables)***  and I found out one solution to that, but still it was not enough as it was retrieving whole  data from tableS of bills and payments. As per the tip I got from there, I have reached another solution, which is as follows:

First of all I created a type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE key_id_row AS OBJECT
    (
        key_id number(10)
    );
```

Then created a table type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE key_id_tab AS TABLE OF key_id_row;
```

Then created a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_key_id(cons_id VARCHAR2) RETURN key_id_tab IS
    result_tab key_id_tab;    
BEGIN
    SELECT
        key_id_row(key_id)
    BULK COLLECT INTO 
        result_tab
    FROM
        consumer
    WHERE
        cons_id_no = cons_id;
    RETURN result_tab;    
END get_key_id;
```

After that I used it in the query as follows:

```
SELECT
    c.key_id,
    c.cons_id_no consumerid,
    b.bill_id_no,
    b.key_id,
    b.bill_date,
    m.key_id,
    m.receipt_no,
    m.pay_date    
FROM
    consumer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            bb.bill_id_no,
            gk.key_id,
            bb.bill_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY bb.key_id ORDER BY bb.bill_date DESC) AS rowNumber
        FROM
            bm_bill bb
        JOIN
            TABLE(get_key_id('2114109999')) gk
        ON
            (gk.key_id = bb.key_id)    
    ) b
ON
    (b.rowNumber = 1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            gk.key_id,
            mr.receipt_no,
            mr.pay_date,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mr.key_id ORDER BY mr.pay_date DESC) rowNumber
        FROM
            mreceipt mr
        JOIN
            TABLE(get_key_id('2114109999')) gk
        ON
            (gk.key_id = mr.key_id)
    ) m
ON
    (m.rowNumber = 1)        
WHERE
    c.cons_id_no='2114109999';
```

Is the solution good enough or Do I have to approach the problem in the following way:

Select the key_id from the consumer table as a separate query as in:

```
SELECT key_id FROM consumer WHERE cons_id_no = '2114109999';
```

and store it in a variable and use that value inside the query I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution currently is creating table of the key_ids associated with each consumer id.  If you only need the latest then the answer on your other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15575901/2232918) is correct. Since you are aggregating the latest values from your bill and payment tables a sub-query join on an ordered table is the best way to go.

I am not sure what you mean by retrieving whole data from the bills and payments tables.  If you mean full table scans then this should be relieved by appropriate indexing and/or partitioning.

Do you intend your ledger to be a full list of all bills and payments by the consumer?  Your question gives the impression you only care about the latest.

Comment: I need only latest. In the previous query, the query on the left outer join is retrieving the all rows from the table. To avoid that I used the function, now I think it is an overkill

Comment: Okay. The sub-queries in the solution are going to be querying the full table but you can use indexes and table partitions to help pinpoint where to look on those tables for the ranking however based on the implementation they are only returning the first record where rownum =1 so if it is returning many records then something is not correct in your implementation.  I do agree using a function is overkill especially since you really only need one record from each of your source tables.